# A question regarding the proof of theorem 1.21 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

On page 10 of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Rudin makes a claim that the identity

$b^{n} - a^{n} = (b - a)(b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}a + \cdots + a^{n-1})$

yields the inequality   $b^{n} - a^{n} < (b - a)nb^{n-1}$ when $0 < a < b$, for real $a$ and $b$, and natural $n$.

Is this result obvious or does it actually require proving? Rudin gives no explanation for why it's true and I failed at finding any obvious reasons for it being true.

Comment: If $0<a<b$ then $b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+\cdots+a^{n-1}<b^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+\cdots+b^{n-1}=nb^{n-1}$

Comment: Do you agree that $b^{n-i}a^{i-1}<b^{n-1}$ since $0<a<b$?

Comment: Hint: if $0<a<b$, then $a^j<b^j$ for any positive integer $j$. Use this fact in the second pair of parentheses.

Comment: You need $n\ge2$; for $n=1$ you have equality.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $0<a<b$, then $a^j<b^j$ for any positive integer $j$,

so $b^{n-1-j}a^j<b^{n-1-j}b^j=b^{n-1}$,

so $b^{n-1}+b^{n-2}a+\cdots+a^{n-1}<b^{n-1}+b^{n-1}+\cdots+b^{n-1}=nb^{n-1}$.